# Responsive Design: Using pixel width divs within fluid design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The setup:

I have a sidebar and a main content column. The sidebar has a 33% width and the main content has a pixel width that fills the rest of the space. I want the main content to stay at its fixed width until it reaches a certain media query break-point and gets smaller. So basically I want just the sidebar to be shrinking as the window resizes until the break-point.

This sounds like it should be simple to me, but I'm having issues. When I shrink the window, the sidebar doesn't shrink fast enough and the main content drops down underneath it. I suppose this is because since the main content isn't shrinking, its px width is taking up a higher and higher percentage of the screen, whereas the sidebar is just taking 33% always.

I feel like there is some easy solution but I can't come up with it. Any ideas?

Thanks, gals and guys

Comment: Hey. Got a jsfiddle or code example? You could try using % on the main content but add max and min width in pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview

If you make your content box 67%, and comment out whitespace between div's it should work.

I also added `box-sizing:border-box;` because then you can add padding and it won't add onto the total width.

This does **NOT** apply to margin, you must use margin percentage so that the margins+widths =100% if you want it to fit correctly with margins.

The background colors are only to showcase what the div's look like.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZwbF/

**HTML:**

```
<div id='container'>
<div class='sidebar'>
    Sidebar Test
</div><!--
--><div class='content'>
    Content Test
</div><!--
--></div>
​
```

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar
{
display:inline-block;
width:33%;
box-sizing:border-box;    
background-color:#09f;
}

.content
{
display:inline-block;
width:67%;
box-sizing:border-box;    
background-color:#0F9;
}
```

Comment: But I want the main content div to be fixed width. That's the whole point.

Thanks for the box-sizing tip though. I hadn't heard of that.

Comment: @Brimby what do you want the width to be?

Comment: @Brimby also when do you want content to get smaller and what size should it be when smaller?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I just had to stop trying to fill the whole screen. That's pointless considering people have bigger screens than me. So instead of having a right margin on the content (which I didn't mention) to make it fill the remaining space, I floated it left. Now I'll put a max-width on the sidebar, and make media queries for when the resize catches up to the content box.